# Visual Studio 2015 RC Professional Installation Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I keep on getting the Access denied error while installing VS 2015 RC Professional version. But I was able to install Community edition, but It dont have all features.

[image]

I tried the workaround mentioned in msdn known issues, but no use. I am struck here from past two days.

Thanks is Advance.

Comment: Run the installer from an administrator account. *Access denied* means your account doesn't have privileges to write to the install location, and that location is `%ProgramFiles%`, which requires adminstrator rights.

Comment: I am running the installer as Admin only, and I was successfully able to install Community edition, I am getting only problm with Professional edition

Comment: check the log file to see where the "access denied" error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

try this http://othermisllaneous.blogspot.in/2015/08/update-for-microsoft-windows-kb2999226.html

manually install the file "Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" from "$VS folder\packages\Patch\x64" .
then run it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: manually installing "Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" from "$VS folder\packages\Patch\x64" did the trick for me  (on windows 8.1 system)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. If you look closely, the errors are different.

Answer (score 0):

As  the  access  denied  message  is  shown  install  the  Setup  in  some  other  drives.The  drive  you  are currently  installing may  have some  restrictions  to get installed into  it.[Always use  Admin  privilege  to  install  with  anti-virus  disabled till  install  ]

Thanks.

Comment: I have only one drive (because it is my office workstation), and I disable the antivirus before installing. Interesting thing is it is only happening for Professional version. I had no issues with community edition and enterprise edition. Anyways I installed Enterprise edition now..no issues while installation. I will stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows 8.1 environment, I was having the same issue. So, I did following to fix it.

First followed this,

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968003, to fix the acl if in case,

restarted tried again, it didn't worked :( ..

Then in this same post, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/hal_ provided the solution so I followed that.

First Download the iso file,

right click on the file and mount the file. following commands assume, the iso was mounted on D:, if you have a different location just replace that.

open command prompt in admin mode, run following commands

cd /
c:
mkdir vs2015fix
cd vs2015fix
wusa.exe D:\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu /extract:extractedFix
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:extractedFix\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.cab
D:\packages\vcRedistD14\vc_redist.x64.exe /repair

Above commands do following

change current directory to root
change current drive to c:
make a directory called "vs2015fix"
change current directory to vs2015fix
extracts the patch from D:\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu to a new directory called extractedFix inside vs2015fix
installs the patch using command line tool dism.exe
runs the vc_redist.x64.exe with repair option

after running the above command the right clicked on D:\vs_enterprise.exe and clicked on run as administrator.

that kind of kicked off the installed and it started installing, at the time of writing, it did reached till installing Android Sdk will put the details of how did it go later :)

Following is the link to fix this

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/64baed8c-b00c-40d5-b19a-99b26a11516e/visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2015-rc-fails-on-windows-server-2012?forum=vssetup#928d4dd3-2d69-4ebb-9cff-c2515f111227

Comment: Please don't post links to websites without including the relevant parts of the solution in the answer itself. If that link goes dead then your answer becomes useless.

Comment: This answer worked for me, whereas the others did not.